# Google authentication and authorization among their apps

Tags: google-workspace, security, authentication, oauth

Google has a bunch of apps like Google+, Gmail, Docs, Reader, etc. Internally, these apps must talk to each other securely to query information/data. I am wondering conceptually how Google implements this secured authentication and authorization among their apps internally. Does anyone know about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They use [OAuth2 for authentication and authorization](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2). There are some slight variations on certain services, for example [Google Drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/about_auth). It depends on exactly which service you want to use.